# Looking for a Specific Planet

Tags: planets, stars, astrophysics

I know my title isn't the most specific, but the planet I am looking for is. I have been looking through many exoplanets and I can't seem to find what I am looking for, the closest I have found is [TRAPPIST-1h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRAPPIST-1h). The issue is I do not believe that an anti-greenhouse effect could lower the temperature enough to make it suitable.

What I am looking for is a terrestrial planet, under six earth masses, at an equilibrium temperature of around ninety degrees Kelvin, and is within the Aquarius constellation. The star of the planet doesn't have to be visible to an earthbound audience, and the equilibrium temperature can be above or below ninety, as long as greenhouse or anti-greenhouse effects could theoretically make the surface temperature average ninety. A preference for the star it orbits to be a [population II star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_population#Population_II_stars), but that is not a requirement. Based on these parameters are there any planetary candidates?

Comment: If you want a planet to place the story, just name it "Blahblah" around a star in the more distant part of Milky Way, or however your galaxy is called out there. If you need a *real, existing* world to run a science based story, you might get better answers in Astronomy.SE.

Comment: @Vesper I am aware I can make up a planet, it’s simply my preference to at least attempt to find one with these qualifications first. But your right the Astronomy SE might be of some help as well.

Comment: Bad idea to chose a real planet IMHO. There are several new space telescopes on the way, and better land ones too. By the time you have written your book, any known facts about your real planet will have been overwritten. I am in favour of getting the science right if you can, but picking an actual planet is risky.

Comment: @RichardKirk I agree that its generally best to make up your own setting, but I disagree with the idea that discovering that a real location is not as the story imagined detracts from the story. See "All Summer in a Day" by Ray Bradbury. Great story which is set on Venus, except its a rainforest.

Comment: @RichardKirk Well I have a reason for why I am using known exoplanets rather than making my own up. If I didn't have a reason to use real planets I would go the route of making up planets in unknown parts.

Comment: Do you need a real exoplanet, or could a real-ish exoplanet designation do the trick? You could make up a designation based on existing rules, and then give it a cool, IAU-approvable name.

Comment: Just an advice. Kelvin doesn't come with degrees.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a real planet matching the features you want, you are in the wrong time: the way we detect planets outside of our solar system is via the perturbation that those planets cause to their central star, either in the orbit or luminosity.

A planet at 90 K would be quite far from its star or the star would need to be very dim, and having a rather small mass would not perturbate the star luminosity enough to be detectable with our current state of the art telescopes.

But luckily for you, fictional worlds do not need real planets. See Star Wars and all the planets it uses: not finding them on a stellar atlas doesn't detract to the story.

Comment: Well that can’t be the case or we wouldn’t know about OGLE-2005-BLG-390L b.

Comment: @Amoeba - OGLE-2005-BLG-390L b is a super-earth that perturbed the luminosity of its star (just as L.Dutch said) by gravitational lensing as it transited its star. which is, indeed, itself quite dim.  In fact, it seems to hit most of your qualifiers.

Comment: @jdunlop I am aware of how they found the planet, my point wasn't that they didn't use perturbation but that planets at that temperature can be found via that method.